# Read argument of an Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#, linq, expression

**EDIT:**

Basically I want to get the values of the parameters of a called method like this:

here is my Expression function look likes

```
    public static bool SearchBy(Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> func, string url)
    {
        var body = func.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (body != null)
        {
            foreach (var argument in body.Arguments)
            {
                var constant = argument as ConstantExpression;

                if (constant != null) //NULL HERE
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(constant.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

my questin is:

How would I read the argument that is passing to a function?

Comment: What do you mean by "read the argument"?

Comment: basically I want to get the values of the parameters of a called method

Comment: You can't know what the argument will be because the argument is not populated at that point. You are defining a function that will operate over a set of data. Also being a `Expression` it is possible that the function is not even evaluated on your computer, the expression could be turned in to a SQL statement and processed inside a SQL server. If you dropped the `Expression` part and where just doing `Func<Employee,bool>` you could do something like what you want to do, but you can't do it with `Expression`.

Comment: @Scott: if i take out the `Expression` getting error not recognizing the `Body`

Comment: Well yea, `Body` is a property of `Expression` you will need to totally re-write the function.

Comment: You should show the callsite as well.

Comment: If you show how you want to use this method, and the `Employee` value that you get, it would help us understand what you need.

Comment: can you provide sample _values of the parameters_ for your code in post?

Answer (score 1):

As noted here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710(v=vs.110).aspx

You can access the parameters of the lambda using the Parameters property. In your example, this would be func.Parameters.

Comment: i updated my question, i did try but i am getting null please see my question

Comment: In your example, you're casting Body (an instance of Expression) to MethodCallExpression and then calling Body.Arguments. Did you actually try func.Parameters instead?

Comment: yes tried, where exactly i would see my parameters in `func.Parameters` i have `count=1`

Comment: Great! Then just access func.Parameters like any List, then. func.Parameters.First() and whatnot.

Comment: i dont have `First` what i see is that `Name` so i do `func.Parameters.Name` i get value `x`

Comment: Parameters implements IEnumerable, so if you add a using for System.Linq you should see all the IEnumerable and IList extension methods. Or, you can run Parameters through a foreach loop.